# Ways to improve searching efficiency

Tags: python, sql, performance, search, big-o

I need a bit of feedback. For one of my projects I'm creating Six degrees of wikipedia. To keep it short I finished all the data cleaning and inserted it into a table into MSSQL. Everything works fine up to this point. I am able to search for a connection from a starting point to end point up until the third degree then it just takes way too long to process. Was looking for ways I can change my code around to increase efficiency. I'm fairly new to this and it's my first time so may not be best way (although I know its probably the worst way I could've done it).

Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

import pyodbc
import time
#import re

#rex = re.compile('(\(\'[a-zA-Z0-9]+\', \')(\w\\))')
start_time = time.time()


listinit = []
listseconditeration = []
listthirditeration = []
listfourthiteration = []
listfifthiteration = []
listsixthiteration = []

start = input ("Select start location :")
finish = input ("Select finish location :")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=johndoe-PC\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=master;UID=-----;PWD=------;Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from join_table where link1 like '%s'" % (start))

rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    listinit.append(row)

for element in listinit:
    var1 = str(element)
    var1 = var1.replace("'","")
    var1 = var1.replace("(","")
    var1 = var1.replace(")","")
    var1 = var1.replace(",","")
    var1 = var1.replace(" ","")
    var1 = var1.replace(start,"")
    listseconditeration.append(var1)


if (finish) in (listseconditeration):
    print("one degree away")
    print("%s minutes" % (time.time() - start_time))


for element in listseconditeration:
    var2 = str(element)

    cursor.execute("select * from join_table where link1 like '%s'" % (var2))
    rows1 = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows1:

        listthirditeration.append(row)

        for element in listthirditeration:
            var3 = str(element)
            var3 = var3.replace("'","")
            var3 = var3.replace("(","")
            var3 = var3.replace(")","")
            var3 = var3.replace(",","")
            var3 = var3.replace(" ","")
            var3 = var3.replace(var2, "")
            listfourthiteration.append(var3)



if (finish) in (listfourthiteration):
    print("two degree away")
    print("%s minutes" % (time.time() - start_time))



for element in listfourthiteration:
    var4 = str(element)

    cursor.execute("select * from join_table where link1 like '%s'" % (var4))
    rows2 = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows2:

        listfifthiteration.append(row)

        for element in listfifthiteration:
            var5 = str(element)
            var5 = var5.replace("'","")
            var5 = var5.replace("(","")
            var5 = var5.replace(")","")
            var5 = var5.replace(",","")
            var5 = var5.replace(" ","")
            var5 = var5.replace(var4, "")
            listsixthiteration.append(var5)
        print(row)


if (finish) in (listsixthiteration):
    print("three degree away")
```

Comment: You should be using `join` in the database to traverse the graph.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I created a join table in database and that's where I imported the tuples from the initial list from. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: May I ask why are you using SQL? This doesn't seem to be the right tool for the job at all, your queries are very specific, and using sql to simply store `(source, destination)` is an overkill.

Comment: Also, please formalize what your expected input and output are.

Comment: It's the way our professor told us to do it, but we told him that no one implemented it this way when we searched online, but he is persistent on us using mssql even with only one table, an example would be chicago->autumn->easter->asia->earth->air->water  chiacgo ->autumn takes 6 seconds and chicago ->autumn-> easter took 190 seconds but when i do the next degree, thats when it took over an hour and completely froze my computer @amit

Comment: Your proff is not an idiot, his goal is to teach you something, not for you to create the program, he doesn't need it to solve his research, he wants you to learn something from the process. You should be more respectful.

Comment: @amit Sorry i'm working in a group with a couple friends and we posted this together, one of them posted that and I re-edited it to a more accurate response to what you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues with the code.

The first and most significant issue is that the code doesn't prevent re-processing elements that have already been visited.  For example, when you do chicago->autumn, there isn't anything in your routine to prevent going back to chicago and making a loop. This makes the size of your search grow very rapidly.

One solution is to maintain a set instead of elements that have already been visited:

```
seen = set()

...

    for element in listthirditeration:
        var3 = str(element)
        var3 = var3.replace("'","")
        var3 = var3.replace("(","")
        var3 = var3.replace(")","")
        var3 = var3.replace(",","")
        var3 = var3.replace(" ","")
        var3 = var3.replace(var2, "")

        if var3 not in visited:
            visited.add(var3)
            listfourthiteration.append(var3)
```

...repeat for other similar loops...

A second issue is that the code makes duplicate copies of the lists of elements, and keeps them longer than needed.

```
cursor.execute("select * from join_table where link1 like '%s'" % (var2))

rows1 = cursor.fetchall()           # <<== fetchall() returns a list of results

for row in rows1:

    listthirditeration.append(row)  # <<== this makes a second copy of the results
```

A trick to use when doing a breadth-first search like that, is to do two searches--one from the start toward the end and another from the end toward the start, and have them meet in the middle.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, like a bi-directional breadth first search right? Also thanks a lot for your input, just saying this. Will work on it now ! @RootTwo

Comment: @DavidA you might also want to take a look at using aliases in SQL so you can [`join` a table to itself](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/sql-joining-a-table-to-itself).  You can do multiple levels of the search directly in SQL.